# Why does setting a breakpoint pause execution of my golang process?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging a local running golang 1.17 server process on macOS 12.3 in vscode 1.66.0 (go for vscode 0.32 and dlv 1.7), setting a new breakpoint pauses execution of the process.  I seem to have a mental block over remembering to un-pause the execution, maybe because I don't understand why it pauses the execution, and multiple times per day I sit there waiting a few seconds for a call to complete, or to trip the breakpoint, before the light bulb flickers on and I remember to manually un-pause the debugger.

I haven't found if this behaviour is modifiable, like a launch.json setting or something in dlv or the vscode extension, because I very much would like it to *not* pause the vm when I set a breakpoint.  Is this possible?  If it's something required of the environment, then ok, but if not, then I'd wonder if there's some purpose behind it I don't understand.

Comment: Internally, you have to stop something before you reach in and fiddle with its innards. It's just a bug (bug-ette? little bug?) if the debugger forgets to auto-resume, but it sure is annoying, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dlv v1.7.3 fixed the issue and auto-resumes execution
https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#added-3 The latest dlv version is 1.8.2